# Scalaz Type Classes for Apache Spark RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, rdd, scalaz

The goal is to implement different type classes (like Semigroup, Monad, Functor, etc.) provided by Scalaz for Spark's RDD (distributed collection). Unfortunately, I cannot make any of the type classes that take higher kinded types (like Monad, Functor, etc.) to work well with RDDs.

RDDs are defined (simplified) as:

```
abstract class RDD[T: ClassTag](){
   def map[U: ClassTag](f: T => U): RDD[U] = {...}
}
```

Complete code for RDDs can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala).

Here is one example that works fine:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

implicit def semigroupRDD[A] = new Semigroup[RDD[A]] {
   def append(x:RDD[A], y: => RDD[A]) = x.union(y)
}
```

Here is one example that doesn't work:

```
implicit def functorRDD =  new Functor[RDD] {
   override def map[A, B](fa: RDD[A])(f: A => B): RDD[B] = {
      fa.map(f)
   }
}
```

This fails with:

> error: No ClassTag available for B
>                      fa.map(f)

The error is pretty clear. The map implemented in RDD expects a ClassTag (see above). The ScalaZ functor/monads etc., do not have a ClassTag. **Is it even possible to make this work without modifying Scalaz and/or Spark?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: no

For type classes like `Functor`, the restriction is that for **any** `A` and `B`, unconstrained, given `A => B` you have a function lifted `RDD[A] => RDD[B]`. In Spark you cannot pick arbitrary `A` and `B`, since you need a `ClassTag` for `B`, as you saw.

For other type classes like `Semigroup` where the type doesn't change during the operation and therefore does not need a `ClassTag`, it works.

Comment: This was my conclusion as well.